# How to know when a new record is added to the database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database

I have a database being used by two different applications. 
Application1 will perform all the operations in the database. We do not have control on this application

Application2 will need to be alerted when there is a addition, modification or deletion of a record from a table.
But we cannot write some triggers in sql.

Example: There is a billing software which adds a bill to the bills table and the respective record in the customer table will be updated with the new points obtained from the bill.
Now we have a different software for analysis which retrieves the data from the customers table and issue some vouchers to them dynamically. I can't loop or query the db very frequently unless it is the only option left.

I also want to know if there is a feature in database engine.

Any suggestions please..

Comment: You've tagged this as MySql AND sql-server, which is confusing.

Comment: @Stuart: sorry yaar, probably the updated question gives a bit of meaning for tagging.

Answer (score 5):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/using-and-monitoring-sql-2005-query-notification/).

Answer (score 3):

App1 sends a message to App2, before/after the DB manipulation.

Comment: sorry, i have modified the question now. We do not have any control on the app1

Comment: @Michael, yes I know, but if triggers are not allowed... what else could you do?

Comment: Middleman service that talks to the DB and then informs App2 based on what the DB returned, something like Gearman.

Comment: could idea, but if he cannot edit app1 it´s kind a difficult?!

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us some context, for example what the application is, what the changes are etc?  Is it just triggers that are prohibited?  (Why is this?).

You might be left polling the DB in a loop, checking `SELECT MAX(id) FROM table` to see if the ID is bigger than last time (i.e. something new is there).  Without triggers you can't see modification or deletion, unless you wrote App1 and can have it write to an audit table at the same time, logging all operations.

Comment: @Johnstone: ok. I am updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

"But we cannot write some triggers in sql."

That is the only way possible, if you want your system to be reliable and if you want it provide correct information to its users *at all times* (and if a possible way there is - see further).

Someone answered "App1 sends a message to App2", to which the remark was given "Not ACID compliant".  The remark is correct (given some reasonable interpretation of the term 'ACID').  The point is, your app2 only wants to receive, say, insert notifications, at the point where it is *absolutely certain* that an insert really has happened.  That point of certainty is only reached when the *DBMS* has *successfully committed* such an insert.

Hence, the trigger you would need is a kind of trigger that runs after a succesfull commit (do those exist ?).

And then the problem becomes, what should happen to the committed data if that commit trigger fails for any reason ?  Your data is committed, your app1 thinks everything is OK, but your app2 still hasn't received the notification it should have gotten.

The solution to this problem is that your app1, and your DBMS, and your app2, should all be prepared to engage in a two-phase commit.  I have little doubt that since you "cannot do anything to app1", it will also be impossible for you to make it engage in a 2PC.

The "database listeners" pattern is, plain and simple, flawed design.  At least if you cherish "absolute consistency".

Answer (score 0):

May be you can track those change by the advice that was given in these links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305322(v=sql.110).aspx

or try to do a cherche in google with the following:
who to trace change database mssql

Comment: If the answer can be found within those links, then you should summarize the content within your answer and  use the links as a reference. Just linking to another site for an answer isn't considered a high quality response.

Comment: Thanks I will do a review ASAP